# How to save excel file from fron-end with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

i have a rest api with spring boot that works fine it uploads an excel file in temporary file then it adds it to the database

However i am a beginner in angular Js so i am not able to do that even after a long search on the internet i will appreciate any help

here is my code for the rest API

```
@RestController
public class UploadController {
@Autowired
PosteDao posteDao ;
//Save the uploaded file to this folder
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C://Temp//";
@PostMapping("/doUploadFile") // //new annotation since 4.3
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
        return "redirect:uploadStatus";
    }

    try {

        // Get the file and save it somewhere
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
        processExcel();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "greaat";
}

public String processExcel() throws IOException      { 


      try {

            InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:\\\\list.xlsx");
            //définir l'objet workbook
            XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);  
            //Itérer sur le nombre de sheets
            for(int i=0;i<wb.getNumberOfSheets();i++)
            {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
            //Itérer sur les lignes
            Row row;
            for(int k=1;k<sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;k++)
            {

                row = (Row) sheet.getRow(k);  //sheet number

                    int idPoste;
                    if( row.getCell(0)==null) { idPoste = 0; }
                    else idPoste= (int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                       String libelle;
                    if( row.getCell(1)==null) { libelle = "null";}  //suppose excel cell is empty then its set to 0 the variable
                       else libelle = row.getCell(1).toString();   //else copies cell data to name variable
                    System.out.println(libelle);
                    System.out.println(idPoste);


            }

        }} catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Erreur");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "data extracted successfully";
    }
```

}

Comment: I want to save my excel file in database from the front-end the rest api i developped earlier can do that it saves it but i want to do it with angular js

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33119193/how-to-upload-excel-file-in-angular-js ? Was it helpful ?

Comment: yeah i have checked that earlier this morning i does not help because my issue is a little bit different all i want is to pass the excel file from the UI to the rest api

Comment: You can also try https://github.com/agershun/alasql if you want to just parse the excel file into a JSON object and pass that to the backend.